# VBA - How to tell 13 combinatios by randomize to remain under 100?

Tags: excel, vba, random

I would like to randomize 13 variables which in sum **have to** be 100%.

For a better understanding I show you what I mean by a snippet. From column F to column R all variables have to understand that in sum (column S) these are not allowed to be over 100.

Each row shall be another scenario, so the rows by itself are independent.
[image]

My approach was like the following but unfortunately nothing happens. Anyone an idea? Thanks a lot.

```vb
Sub Zufall()
    Dim k As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("F11:R55").ClearContents
    DoEvents

    Do Until WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("S11:S55")) = 100
        Randomize
        For k = Columns(19) To Columns(6) Step -1
            Cells(11, k).Formula = Int(Rnd() * 100)
        Next k
        Range("R55:F11").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("S11:S55"))
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code shows how to generate a set of n random single precision numbers between 0 and 1 which sum to 1.

```
' Returns an array of random numbers (0 <= n < 1) which sum to 1.
' Size is the size of the array to return.
Function GenerateRandomNumbers(ByVal size As Integer) As Variant
    
    ReDim vals(1 To size) As Single
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim sum As Single
    
    For idx = 1 To size
        vals(idx) = Rnd
        sum = sum + vals(idx)
    Next idx
    
    For idx = 1 To size
        vals(idx) = vals(idx) / sum
    Next idx
    
    GenerateRandomNumbers = vals
    
End Function
```

You use it like this.

```
 Sub Randomm()
 
    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim thirteenRandomNumbersWhichSumToOne As Variant
 
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        
        For row = 6 To 50
        
            thirteenRandomNumbersWhichSumToOne = GenerateRandomNumbers(13)
            
            For col = 6 To 18 ' F to R
                
                .Cells(row, col).Value = thirteenRandomNumbersWhichSumToOne(col - 5)
                .Cells(row, col).NumberFormat = "0%"
            
            Next col

            .Cells(row, 19).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC6:RC18)"
            .Cells(row, 19).NumberFormat = "0%"
            
        Next row
        
    End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! It works but just the numbers within rng do no limit itself up to 100%  in column S there has always to be the calculated range of the row = 100% ..any idea? I put the edited code below

Answer (score 2):

This will generate 13 values from **A1** through **A13**:

```
Sub Randomm()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, rng As Range
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set rng = Range("A1:A13")
    
    rng.Formula = "=RAND()"
    rng.Value = rng.Value
    zum = wf.Sum(rng)
    For i = 1 To 13
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value / zum
    Next i
    rng.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thank :) i posted my answer below because there is one last question. Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

this is the current and last code. Missing:

- idx values in sum do not limit up to 100% in column S

Changed:

- column S was implied by using the easy sum calcluation in Excel
- the % wasnt shown right this is why i used it by Format in Excel

  ```
   Sub Randomm()
   Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, rng As Range, zum As Single, i As    Integer
   Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
   Set rng = Range("F6:R50")
   Dim totalRow As Single

   rng.Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(5,25)/100"
   rng.Value = rng.Value
   zum = wf.sum(rng)
   For i = 6 To 50
       Cells(i, 6).Value = Cells(i, 13).Value

   Next i


   End Sub

   Function GenerateRandomNumbers(ByVal size As Integer) As Variant

   ReDim vals(1 To size) As Single
   Dim idx As Integer
   Dim sum As Single

   For idx = 1 To size
       vals(idx) = Rnd

   Next idx

   For idx = 1 To size
       vals(idx) = vals(idx)
   Next idx

   GenerateRandomNumbers = vals

   End Function
  ```

[image]

Comment: Just adding my function to the module doesn't help anything, you have to actually _call it from your code_. Also, the changes you made to the code I gave you (you removed two lines) would have broken it, so maybe it's just as well you didn't call it. I have updated my answer above to provide you with a complete solution.

Comment: thanks a lot @Nicholas Hunter...to be honest i had never had done it by myself. Its way levels over my knowledge, i just knew that you have to apply a function on a code...understand the code is one thing but to write it a totally other. Can i ask you for how long you are doing this? And is there any book, page you can recommend? I really appreciate your time and effort...dont knwo what to say, thanks!

Comment: I have been working with Excel and VBA for 10+ years. I have been writing computer software in various different languages for 40+ years. Like anything else, it gets easier if you keep doing it. There are lots of books & website out there to learn Excel forumulas & macros. I don't know of any in particular I would recommend.