# How to generate random quantites until reach a certain number

Tags: excel, vba, loops, random

"I want to generate random numbers (with limits for each case(item number))
until reach specific number (which is the sum of the total column) "

;this is a a daily sales list for a restaurant, I want to ask the code to generate quantities that will lead to specific totals sales, the unit price column is fixed

This code is working but I can't choose specific value to reach but I have to choose range, and the other problem is when th range difference is small the code take too much time to solve the problem and it still working ..."
[image: table]
[image: present code]

```
Sub mad()

Do Until Range("A54").Value > Range("j54").Value And Range("A54").Value < Range("j55").Value

For i = 11 To 51
Select Case i
Case 12, 14, 15, 16, 33 To 36
'Small and medium meal'
Cells(i, 3).Value = Int((VBA.Rnd * 12) + 3)

Case 11, 13, 17, 37
'big meals'
Cells(i, 3).Value = Int((VBA.Rnd * 6) + 1)

Case 20 To 28
'sandwitches and snacks'
Cells(i, 3).Value = Int((VBA.Rnd * 4) + 1)

Case 29 To 32, 38 To 40, 45 To 47
'small snacks, potato, cheese'
Cells(i, 3).Value = Int((VBA.Rnd * 3) + 0)

Case 41
'cola 250 ml '
Cells(i, 3).Value = Int((VBA.Rnd * 15) + 1)

Case 42 To 44
'cola 1 & 2 ltr'
Cells(i, 3).Value = Int((VBA.Rnd * 4) + 0)

Case Else
'addtitions'
Cells(i, 3).Value = Int((VBA.Rnd * 3) + 0)
End Select



Next i

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: for i= 11 to 51 are the rows that will quantities will be generated to

Comment: Use the Solver, can find values and easy to limit them to a min or max.

Comment: thank you it was nice to learn about solver, nice tool, but it take too much time to solve for my case

Comment: Maybe this will help? [This code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67141679/3817068) shows how to generate a set of n random single precision numbers between 0 and 1 which sum to 1.

Comment: I saw the code but it is not working for my case at all, thanks